# awk to print shell variable in specific column

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to pass a shell variable to a specific column $3 in a file. The `awk` executes buts only prints the header row. Thank you :).

**file** `tab-delimited`

```
ID POS X LOC
1 222  aaa
2 555  bbb
```

**awk**

```
b=123
awk -v x="$b" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1 {print $3=$3"x"} 1' file
```

**output**  `tab-delimited`

```
ID POS X LOC
```

**desired**   `tab-delimited`

```
ID POS x LOC
1 222 123 aaa
2 555 123 bbb
```

Comment: Do you want the space between `123` and the current value for `$3` to be a tab or space?

Comment: is the intention to ***add*** a new column, or ***prepend*** a value a current column; in other words, is that a space or a tab between `123` and `aaa`?

Comment: The script you posted cannot produce the output you say it does from the input you posted since a) `NR>1 {print $3=$3"x"}` will print every line after the first with a trailing `x` added and b) `1` print every line (so all but the first line would print twice.) so it's impossible for it to only output the single line `ID POS X LOC`. Please correct your example, it's important to show us the real problem you're trying to solve so we can help you with it.

Comment: There is a tab between $3 and $4 and the 123 value is prepended to the empty $3. Thank you :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following awk code.

```
awk -v x="$b" '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
NR>1  {
  $3= x " " $3
}
1
' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, assuming you want to insert `x` if `$3` is empty

```
% awk -v x="$b" -v OFS="\t" -F '\t' '$3 == ""{$3 = x}1' file
ID  POS X   LOC
1   222 123 aaa
2   555 123 bbb
```